# Аутентификация и авторизация в Spring Security через бд postgresql

Tags: java, авторизация, spring-security, аутентификация

Прошу помощи в понимании ошибки, связанной с авторизацией.
Есть класс WebSecurityConfig

```
package kotiki.controllers.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT login AS username, password, 'true' AS enabled FROM users WHERE login=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "SELECT login AS username, name AS role " +
                        "FROM user_roles " +
                            "JOIN users " +
                                "ON users.id = user_id " +
                        "JOIN roles " +
                                "ON roles.id = role_id " +
                        "WHERE login=?");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN", "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Класс User

```
package kotiki.dao.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

//    @ManyToMany
//    @JoinTable(
//            name = "user_roles",
//            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
//    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Класс Role

```
package kotiki.dao.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    public Role() {}

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Set<User> getUsers() { return users; }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) { this.users = users; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(users);
        return "Role{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", users=" + users +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Таблица users**
[image: Таблица users]

**Таблица user_roles**
[image: Таблица user_roles]

**Таблица roles**
[image: Таблица roles]

При авторизации через [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M0gX.png) всегда выдаёт ошибку 403, за исключением обращения по адресу /user/** 
[image: postman]

Не могу понять в чём может быть дело. 
Очень надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: ну на `/user/**` пускает, потому что вы сами в конфиге указали `antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()`

Comment: вечером или ночью посмотрю если никто раньше не ответит

Comment: скопировал вашу конфигурацию...и у меня все работает. где надо требует авторизацию. после авторизации пропускает

Comment: где контроллер который `/cat/get_all` обрабатывает?

Comment: @МихаилРебров да, я перезапустил Ubuntu, запустил заново приложение и у меня тоже всё заработало!
Я ничего не менял, просто перезагрузился...